# "Not speaking" vs. "not having spoken."

Tags: word-choice, phrase-usage

> His tongue was stiff, the consequence of **not speaking/not having
> spoken** in a whole year.

Does the meaning change a lot if you choose one option or the other? Or maybe adding *having* is superfluous in this sentence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The choice of **not speaking** and **not having spoken** depends on the context and construction of the sentence.

**Not speaking** has no tense, like **not smoking** and **not drinking**. It can be used in present, past and future contexts.

**Not having spoken** is a phrase that sets the scene in the past. It leads naturally to whatever follows as a consequence.

**Not speaking during the lecture is/was the advice given to the students.**

**Not having spoken during the lecture, he raised his hand to ask a question.**

**Not speaking for an entire year** means not saying anything for 365 days, by implication for a calendar year.

**Not speaking in an entire year** is not idiomatic. We don't say that someone didn't speak **in** an hour or **in** a day. I would disagree with RobJarvis's interpretation of the distinction.

Comment: Just for the record, I did not say that __not speaking in an entire year__ is idiomatic, nor did I mean to imply such. I do understand, however, that not everyone will agree with the distinction I made in my answer between __in__ and __for__.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use **not speaking**, you will need to follow it with a different adverbial phrase, like so:

> His tongue was stiff, the consequence of not speaking **for** a whole year.

The difference is that **in** would mean "sometime during" while **for** gives the sense "for the entire duration."

> His tongue was stiff, the consequence of not having spoken **in** a whole year.

In this case, **in** is acceptable, because **not having spoken** gives the reader the understanding that the act of not speaking was a constant in the past, and the temporally inclusive sense of **for** is not needed. The writer could, however, in this case choose to use **for** as well without changing the meaning.